# decrease x-axis labels area height for grouped categories highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How could I decrease the cells height on x-axis as there are lots of empty spaces. I have used x-axis grouped-categories.js plug in. As you could see in the picture, the grey lines on x-Axis are too long and occupying too much space of my chart-container.
Below is the code which I have used for the chart:

```
xAxis: {
                categories: [{
                    name: "Year 7",
                    categories: [1, 2, 3, 4]
                }, {
                    name: "Year 8",
                    categories: [1, 2, 3, 4]
                }, {
                    name: "Year 9",
                    categories: [1, 2, 3, 4]
                }, {
                    name: "Year 10",
                    categories: [1, 2, 3, 4]
                }, {
                    name: "Year 11",
                    categories: [1, 2, 3, 4]
                }],
                drawHorizontalBorders: false,
                labels: {
                    rotation: 0,
                    groupedOptions: [{
                        y: 4,
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '5.5px',
                            padding: 0
                        }
                    }],
                    y: 7,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '5.5px',
                        padding: 0
                    }
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    color: '#5DA06E',
                    width: 2,
                    value: l
                }, {
                    color: '#5DA06E',
                    width: 2,
                    value: m
                }],
                min: m + 0.5,
                max: l - 0.5
            },

            yAxis: [{
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                min: 0,
                max: 1000
            },
                {
                    gridLineWidth: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: false
                    },
                    labels: {
                        align: 'left',
                        x: 5,
                        formatter: function () {
                            var value = change[this.value];
                            return value !== 'undefined' ? value : this.value;
                        },
                        style: {
                            font: '8px arial'
                        }
                    },
                    tickPositions: [0, lines[0][1], lines[1][1], lines[2][1], lines[3][1], lines[4][1], lines[5][1], lines[6][1], lines[7][1], lines[8][1]],
                    gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                    opposite: true,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 1000
                }],
```

[image]

Comment: What code did you use to create these cells?

Comment: I just added the code.

Comment: Only thing to manage labels are options: `x`, `y` and `style.padding`.  The last one should take up some space, but without modifying source it may not be possible to change by options. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TFhd7/375/ - I tried also to change size returned by `groupSize()` method - play around with it, maybe you will get acceptable results.

Comment: Thanks for the hint which is fine for one chart. As I do not quite understand the added function, how could I use that for other chart? Thansk

Comment: I found out by using "marginBottom: 25" I can remove excess space from bottom of chart

Comment: Wrapped method modifies `size`, which is used later in calculations for ticks and labels positions. See source code for more info.